# Can't tag business in Facebook photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, photos, facebook-tags

Our business has posted some photos to Facebook for a corporate event. We wish to tag the company who held the event in the photos. When we click to tag, their name will not appear in the results. This happens for 2 different companies. I have Liked those companies with no difference.

How do I tag a business in a Facebook photo?

Edit: I am an admin of our business page.

Comment: You're the admin of the page, but you want to tag another company page that you're not an admin of, right?

Answer (score 2):

You have to be the admin of the page to be able to tag it.

One work around is to type the complete name of the Company while adding the tag. Even when no match is showing up, press enter. The Company would be tagged but there would be no link to any page when we click on the Tag.